# Reshape MATLAB matrix with repeated indicies

Tags: matlab, sorting, reshape

I apologize if this is a repeated question.

Suppose I have a matrix A

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

and a vector b `[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]`. Thus, matrix `A` contains multiple ordered measurements based on vector `b`.

How can I reshape the matrix to have dimension `[2 2 4]`, such that `A(:,:,1) = [0,4;8,3]`?

I understand I need to `reshape`. I tried using `permute`, however it does not handle repeated indices.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the output have anything to do with `b`?

Comment: Are you looking for a generic solution for arbitrary b or is b always of the pattern above? For the later much simpler solutions are possible.

Comment: The matrix A is the data corresponding to channels given by b. The actual matrix is much larger, and b runs from 1-6. I need to separate the data by the channels as mentioned in the question.

Comment: I was thinking of using A(:) and repmat the b vector to match to appropriately (two columns)  then use sort to sort by the second column, but this sounds inefficient. . .

Comment: Why would someone down vote this. These forums boggle my mind sometimes. . . I cannot even delete my own post (clearly people do not find it helpful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, you just need to sort the columns before reshaping them

```
A=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7; 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6]

%A =
%     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
%     8     9     1     2     3     4     5     6

b=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]

%b =
%     1     2     3     4     1     2     3     4 

[~,idx]=sort(b)

%idx =
%     1     5     2     6     3     7     4     8

A=A(:,idx)

%A =
%     0     4     1     5     2     6     3     7
%     8     3     9     4     1     5     2     6

A=reshape(A,[2,2,4])

%A(:,:,1) =
%     0     4
%     8     3

%A(:,:,2) =
%     1     5
%     9     4

%A(:,:,3) =
%     2     6
%     1     5

%A(:,:,4) =
%     3     7
%     2     6
```

Be careful, this will only work if you can assure that each number in `b` is repeated same number of times.

Comment: What kind of wizardry is this!? This is great, thanks so much! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your b is always some repeated 1:n pattern like it is in your question, you can use:

```
p=4 % number of indices
permute(reshape(A,size(A,1),p,[]),[1,3,2])
```